# Azure Pipelines Exclude Commit Message from Pipeline Name

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My pipeline name is set as

```
name: $(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)
```

this works but Azure Pipelines still includes the commit message in my pipeline name. For example, the pipelines UI shows:

```
#20200422.2 The commit message
```

is there a way to get Azure Pipelines to just use the name I specified?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to get Azure Pipelines to just use the name I specified?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

This behavior is **by designed** and is not a bug. I do not believe there is a way to set Azure Pipelines name without submit message.

Including the submit message in the name of the pipeline helps us find the cause of the pipeline failure faster.

For example:

[image]

Just like above build history, We could directly judge the cause of the failed pipeline by the same submit information, not from the code update, more from the task settings and pipeline settings.

On the other hand, We could judge that the pipeline failure may be due to the update of the code according to the different submit information. Then we check the submit record through the submitted history, and we will quickly know which code we have modified to cause the build to fail, which provides great convenience.

**This is especially important for those pipelines that enable CI.(
Enable continuous integration).**

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: the problem is that my pipeline definition is stored in an external repository that only has pipeline yml files (for security reasons so no one can edit the pipeline definition). so my pipeline is then checking out the code from the repository it wants to build using the checkout task. is there a way i can get the commit message in the label to track the repository with the source code, not the pipeline?

Comment: @Jeff, I afraid not. We could use REST API to get the commit message and track the commit message to get the commit ID. But we could not get the source code by the REST API, there is no such API to get the source code.

Comment: @Jeff, You are welcome and I am sorry I didn't help you solve this problem

Comment: Where can we report this as "unhelpful"? I do the same as Jeff (my build and deploy tasks are in a template seperate from the pipeline file) and this causes no end of headache. Even if it is just a character sequence that indicates not to add the commit message. Something to get that message out of my way.

Answer (score 3):

[As of late 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pipeline?view=azure-pipelines#properties), you can now use `appendCommitMessageToRunName` to control commit messages being added to your pipeline title.

To disable them, add `appendCommitMessageToRunName: false` to the root of your YAML pipeline.